# Square point of sale web app-"auto_return" does not work

Tags: square-connect

I am setting the return to true, but when i complete the payment on square, the app does not redirect on its own.

```
{
    "amount_money": {
      "amount" : "100",
      "currency_code" : "USD"
    },
    "auto_return":true,
    "callback_url" : "https://floating-inlet-19449.herokuapp.com/redirect",
    "client_id" : "sq0idp-U8x6mJyLFtHuhCfv9sqL5g",
    "version": "1.3",
    "notes": "notes for the transaction",
    "options" : {
      "supported_tender_types" : ["CREDIT_CARD"]
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto_return` should be nested in the `options` object, like this:

```
{ 
    "amount_money": { "amount" : 100, "currency_code" : "USD" }, 
    "callback_url" : "https://floating-inlet-19449.herokuapp.com/redirect", 
    "client_id" : "sq0idp-U8x6mJyLFtHuhCfv9sqL5g", 
    "version": "1.3", 
    "notes": "notes for the transaction", 
    "options" : { 
        "supported_tender_types" : ["CREDIT_CARD"],
        "auto_return": true
}
```

Comment: @thebigtoeman77, can you mark this as correct so folks know your question was answered?